# findViewById method outside the onCreate method?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

lately, I was working on a very small training project.
But there is one error in my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

    @override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView.setText("Welcome");
    }
}
```

but when I tried to cut the textview global variable and paste it inside the onCreate method, the error has gone. Why is this error occur although I already have inflated the textView in a global variable ?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `findViewById(...)` after calling `setContentView(...)`.

Fetching the view before inflating the layout isn’t possible since there is no view.

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById()` should only be used after `setContentView()` in onCreate.

That's where your entire layout get inflated. Only then you can access views using `findViewById()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;

@override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

    textView.setText("Welcome");

    }
}
```